# Highcharts Tooltip - Access "z" value in series data array

Tags: javascript, tooltip, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts and I'm trying to display the `this.z` value (if possible) in the `tooltip:formatter` section.

This is an example of the json array from  PHP I am passing back to a callbackfunction in javascript:

```
[1315713600000,20,100]
```

I am able to access `this.x` (1315713600000) and `this.y` (20) in the tooltips, but cannot access `this.z` (100) if it's at all possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: This works: this.point.config[2]

Answer (score 2):

Just to close this question:

```
this.point.config[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

When yo create the array in JS you should name the properties

```
data = {x: xValue, y: yValue, z: zValue},
```

And in the tooltip you can call the property like this:

```
this.x
this.y
this.point.z
```